# Richfaces 3.3.2 GA Conditionally show modal panel based on validation

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, facelets

based on this example:

```
              <a4j:commandButton value="Submit"
                        action="#{mappedAction}"
                        eventsQueue="#{eventsQueue}"
                        reRender="#{myId}noteArea"
                        onclick="this.disabled=true"
                        oncomplete="#{facesContext.maximumSeverity == null ? '' : 'this.disabled=false'}" />
```

I'm trying to show and hide a modal panel based on the validation

```
                <a4j:commandButton value="Submit"
                        action="#{mappedAction}"
                        eventsQueue="#{eventsQueue}"
                        reRender="#{myId}noteArea"
                        oncomplete="#{facesContext.maximumSeverity == null ? '' : rich:component(modalConvalida).hide()}"
                        onclick="#{rich:component(modalConvalida)}.show()"
```

/>

Where **modalConvalida** is a ui:param passed into my facelet composite component, but I can't manage to get the syntax right. the panel shows onclick, but it doesn't get hidden in the oncomplete.

If I put an alert in the second branch of the ? operator I can see that it gets executed, though.

Answer (score 0):

Done:

```
                <a4j:commandButton value="Submit"
                        action="#{mappedAction}"
                        eventsQueue="#{eventsQueue}"
                        reRender="#{myId}noteArea"
                        onclick="#{rich:component(modalConvalida)}.show()"
                        oncomplete="#{rich:component(modalConvalida)}.hide()"/>
```

Thanks anyway